# How to get the highest location number from two numbers and insert it to a new int?

Tags: c

I had a task that I need to absorb from the user two int numbers. And to print one number that made from the higher digit in each place.

For example:
Enter 2 numbers: 123456 77553311
print: 77553456.

Enter 2 numbers: 5555 7070707
7075757

So I did this mission but I print every time one number (7 7 5 5...).
How do I enter the new combination to a new num?

This is my code:

```
int main() {
    int num1, num2,sum=0;
    printf("Enter two numbers\n");
    scanf("%d%d", &num1, &num2);
    while ((num1 != 0) || (num2 != 0)) {
        sum *= 10;
        if (num1 % 10 > num2 % 10)
            sum += num1 % 10;
        else
            sum += num2 % 10;
        num1 = num1 / 10;
        num2 = num2 / 10;
    }
    while (sum != 0) {
        printf("%d", sum % 10);
        sum = sum / 10;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How do I enter the new combination to a new num?

Put the entire code in a loop.  Perhaps exit when non-numeric input occurs?

```
int main() {
  for (;;) {  // Loop forever
    int num1, num2, sum = 0;
    printf("Enter two numbers\n");
    if (scanf("%d%d", &num1, &num2) != 2) {
      break;  // Quit the loop
    }
    while ((num1 != 0) || (num2 != 0)) {
      sum *= 10;
      if (num1 % 10 > num2 % 10)
        sum += num1 % 10;
      else
        sum += num2 % 10;
      num1 = num1 / 10;
      num2 = num2 / 10;
    }
    while (sum != 0) {
      printf("%d", sum % 10);
      sum = sum / 10;
    }
    printf("\n");  // add \n
  }
  return 0;
}
```